# Will Tamoe Highland be accessible after I teleport to Tristram in act I

Tags: diablo-ii

In Diablo II, I have in my logs two quests, to go to the Monastery for a hammer.
The monastery is after the area called Tamoe Highland, and I have a quest to go to Tristram and save Deckard Cain.

**My question**, is taking one of those quests will move me to Act II so I won't be able to finish the other one?
Would teleporting to Tristram block me from going back to the Monastery/ Tamoe Highland?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tristam is a very small map. Once you've cleared it out you can take the portal back.

Note that once you've traveled to Act II, you can get back to Act I by using the waypoint system (just change tabs in order to select the act you'd like to access). It's possible to travel between acts.

Comment: Slight correction: to get from Act II to Act I, use the waypoint (change tab) not a town portal.  A town portal takes you from someplace in the act you are in back to the town for that act.

Comment: @purple Thanks I'll update my answer. I googled it before posting since I couldn't remember which was which, but I guess the source was wrong.

Comment: Also, from the town for each act, you can use whomever took you to the next town to go back (until you get to Act IV). But the waypoints are faster and easier.